# transform scale element when keyframe animation applied to it

Tags: css, animation, transform, css-animations

I have an element that has css3 animation with keyframes applied to it but still I want to scale this element. But it seems that because **transform translate** is already applied in the animation **transform scale** is not working

e.g.: let say I have 4 clouds (div elements) moving from right to left, I want those clouds to be different scales

```
.x1 {
  -webkit-animation-name: moveclouds;
  -moz-animation-name: moveclouds;
  animation-name: moveclouds;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 170s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 170s;
  animation-duration: 170s;

  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;

  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  -webkit-transform: scale(0.79);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.79);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.79);
  -o-transform: scale(0.79);
  transform: scale(0.79);
}
.x2{ ...}
.x3{...}
.x4{...}

@keyframes moveclouds {
  from {
    transform: translateX(2400px);
    /* note: I'm using vendor prefixes, I just want to simplified it here */
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
  }
}
```

animation works well, scale not

**question:** anyone got an ide how to enforce the scale ?

I'm using this example http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/pure-css3-animated-clouds-background but tweeking it a bit (see the keyframe difference)

Comment: I tried even to move the "scale" part to different class .y1 or id #y1  still wont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting a CSS property, you must set the complete value for the property.  So in your example you are wanting to set the TRANSFORM property with multiple types of transforms (translateX and scale).  You must set ALL transforms on a single property.  Remove the current SCALE styles, and do the following (with vendor prefixes).  Yes... you will have duplication.  This is a shortcoming of complex CSS3 property values.

```
@keyframes moveclouds {
  from {
    transform: translateX(2400px) scale(0.79);
    /* note: I'm using vendor prefixes, I just want to simplified it here */
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(-200px) scale(0.79);
  }
}
```

To expand on this more, if you had an element with multiple background images:

```
.some-div {
    background-image: url("img1.png"), url("img2.png");
}
```

and you wanted to change `img2.png` to `img3.png` on hover, you would have to:

```
.some-div:hover {
    background-image: url("img1.png"), url("img3.png");
}
```

Comment: yes it worked, but hmm I could swear that I tried this yesterday as well and it wasn't working, oh well late hours aren't productive, thank you